# How to make input appear as sentence case based on typing using angular8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Hi i have an input field, where in based on typing i want to show the text as sentence case, but it is appearing as title case. If i type `"hello hai how are you"` it displays as `"Hello Hai How Are You"` but i want this to appear as `"Hello hai how are you"`, but if user only user CapsLock while typing then it should allow that as priority.

DEMO:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-uppercase-lowercase-xcem7c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fusers%2Fuser.component.html)

DEMO2 with Pipe:

[Pipe Used](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2run8u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="input1">Input Field to be sentense case</label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control text-capitalize" id="input1" placeholder="Name"
     formControlName="name"
     name="name"
      required />
  </div>
```

HTML2:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="myNumber| titleCase" />
</form>
```

TS:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      myNumber: ["hello hai how are you"]
    });
```

pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "titleCase" })
export class TitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(input: string): string {
    console.log(input);
    if (!input) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return input.replace(
        /\b((?!=|\,|\.).)+(.)\b/g,
        first => first.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + first.substr(1)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your request for caps lock to "override" the normal rules elevates this from simple input validation to a quite complicated keyboard input framework, because it breaks a lot of the assumptions made by the underlying technology.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()` along with `.substring()` to achieve the effect like so:

```js
function turnIntoSentence(){
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.value=input.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+input.value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" oninput="turnIntoSentence()">
```

We can force the first letter to be uppercase, and the remaining letters to be lowercase.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
function turnIntoSentence(){
  
  input.value=input.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+input.value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

  if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
    input.value=input.value.toUpperCase();
  }else{
    turnIntoSentence();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" oninput="turnIntoSentence()">
```

You can also leverage an event listener to allow for capitals when CAPS LOCK is enabled.

In the case that you have multiple input fields:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
function turnIntoSentence(){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  input[i].value=input[i].value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+input[i].value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" oninput="turnIntoSentence()">
<input class="input" type="text" oninput="turnIntoSentence()">
<input class="input" type="text" oninput="turnIntoSentence()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how can i use this across the application, i have so many input fields.

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I'll add another snippet in accordance to your situation very quickly.

Comment: this looks like if you hit caps lock it turns the entire text field to uppercase. i may have misunderstood OP, but i think they wanted individual keypresses to be capitalized when capslock is on, while anything that was already typed (with caps lock off) is still capitalized as per the sentence rule.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I thought the OP meant capitalize only if caps lock is on, which would mean all the characters.

Comment: i suppose @Bhrungarajni will have to specify. if i understood correctly, i'm not even sure it's possible with javascript.

Comment: User will make caps lock on for one one or 2 characters, if Caps lock is On what all user types will come in caps, if caps lock is off, then only first character in the input field to be capital rest to be in lowercase

Comment: ya as per my requirement it is working, but i typed "Hello Hai", by keeping caps on, while i was typing "H" for "hai", but i got as "hai"

Comment: @Bhrungarajni As per your question I thought your requirement was to only have the first letter capitalized.

Comment: this works, so 75% it is working, but i have around 100 input fields like this, so instead of writing method to all 100 inputs, is there any way to use as common, i have multiple tabs and multiple components where in i need to use same code so

Comment: can i use same class name to all input fields?

Comment: i tried like this in demo, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-uppercase-lowercase-bz9r2s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fusers%2Fuser.component.ts

Comment: but not working as expected, i get everything in smaller case only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224368/discussion-between-spectric-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

**In your html**:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name"
        formControlName="name"
        name="name"
        #name
        required 
        (input)="handleInputChange(name.value)"/>
```

**In your ts**:

```
handleInputChange(val: string){  
  val = val.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
  this.form.name.setValue(val);
}
```